# how can I catch object return from DLL(C#) in automation anywhere?

Tags: c#, object, dll, bots, automationanywhere

I want to create metabot to get name and age of student as Student object. My method in class library returns student type object. In automation anywhere there are only a few data types as outputs (Value, Array, Password). If you have any idea about catching such object in Automation anywhere please let me know.

This is the object class

```
using System;

namespace TestAADLL
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
        public Student(string n,int a)
        {
           name = n;
           age = a;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class which use this object class and return the instance. I want to catch that return object using data type in automation anywhere.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace TestAADLL
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Student getStudent()
        {
            Student stud = new Student("Anjanee", 90);
            Console.WriteLine(stud);
            Console.WriteLine(stud.age);
            return stud;
        }       
    }
}
```

This is the error i received.

[error recived in Automation anywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3laNw.png)

> Type is not resolved for member 'TestAADLL.Student,TestAADLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

An error occurred at line number 1 of the logic 'testlogic.logic'. Please open the logic in the Logic Editor to view the action at line number 1.

Comment: Have you tried? If yes, can you provide us some code?

Comment: Please add this code in question itself! Not in comments. Also add code to show how you are catching return value and what is the problem.

Comment: Can you please paste error also as text, as images are blocked in some environments?

Comment: I added source code and error in question. thank you shocky and mukesh

Comment: Great! Can your Student class be inherited from MarshalByRefObject. See if that solves your problem. public class Student : MarshalByRefObject.

Comment: thank you mukesh. your solution worked. now object is passing to the promptassignment varibale. thank you so much.

Comment: @AnjaneeNimasha, Glad it helped :). I also added answer with documentation page, so it may help others too.

Comment: yea Mukesh. It is great. in advance as I see we can not do any task by passing the object to automation anywhere. we want to extarct information seperately from object and want to return using seperate methods to do the work within Automation Anywhere. because automation anywhere is not object oriented. Is it correct?

Answer (score -1):

MarshalByRefObject as described in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx) enables access to objects across application domain boundaries in applications that support remoting.

So inheriting your Student class from MarshalByRefObject as below will solve the problem

```
public class Student : MarshalByRefObject
```